# Where does Magento change HTTP to HTTPS in the HTML code?

Tags: magento-1.9, https

So  I was trying to install a SSL certificate on my website, and I prematurely changed the URL's in Magento from http://www.gekra-motors.nl to https://www.gekra-motors.nl.

Now it turns out my host does not support SSL. Worse, I cannot access my Magento admin panel anymore because I changed the URL's  too soon.Now I can only change things in the back-end (directAdmin) and I have to change the URL's back from https to https. So does anyone have a solution or does anyone know how I can get access to the Magento admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

You can update you base url using script. please check below code.

```
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

    $baseUrl = 'http://exampleurl.com/';
    $sql = 'UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = "' . $baseUrl . '" WHERE `path` LIKE "%base_url%"';
    $connection->query($sql);
```

using this revert your base url and access your backend.

another solution is to change base url from database.

execure this query directly into database.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = "http://exampleurl.com/" WHERE `path` LIKE "%base_url%"
```

Also make sure replace "http://exampleurl.com" with your actual base url.

Comment: Please let me know if this solution helps you and also let me know if you need any other help as well.